# What could be the reason to use a current source for potentiometric vane measurement?

Tags: analog, signal, potentiometer

On page number 507 of [this](https://metnet.imd.gov.in/mausamdocs/15948_F.pdf) document, there is a signal conditioner for a potentiometric wind vane.

It seems like they use a current source but I don't get how the mechanism works.

I guess O/P below means the output of the wind vane.

[image]

My questions are:

1. I didn't get how the O/P terminals above is connected to the wind wave. Doesn't such a potentiometric wind vane have 3 terminals? Which terminals are connected to the O/P in this case?
2. Why use a current source? Wouldn't a voltage source and a ratiometric measurement work instead?

I used to measure the vane as in the following model:

[image]

Vs is a voltage source (Rs can be a protective resistor or the output impedance of the supply). R3 and R8 are data acquisition input channel impedances. R2 and R1 represent the vane potentiometer. So in this case Vref and Vout is measured to calculate direction.

**What could be the reason they are using a current source?**

Comment: Note that you'll need to use a dual polarity power supply with the 741 in order for its output to reach the intended 0 to 0.36V output.  The output of a 741 can never get closer than about 2V from the power supply voltages.  With 12V and 0, you get a possible output range between 10V and 2V.  The intended  output of 0 to 0.36 is outside that range.  You would need a power supply with +12V and  about -3V for it to work.  Most folks would just go for a symmetrical +12V and -12V powersupply.

Comment: I see, so can we say better to use an LM324 with a single supply as Russell McMahon suggested?

Comment: If you go the LM324 route, then you would need to change the scaling to use 0 to 5V like Russel McMahon suggests.  The LM324 is better than the 741, but will still only get down to about 20 mV output when using a single rail.  With a scaling of 1degree per millivolt (as in your example) that would be 20 degrees of "dead zone."   With the 360 degrees and 5V scaling that Russel suggests, the "dead zone" would be less than one degree.

Answer (score 1):

From the document you linked: -

[image]

> What could be the reason they are using current source?

To convert resistance (linear with wind direction) to voltage linearly.

> Doesn't such a potentiometric wind vane have 3 terminals?

Not according to the document you linked. They are using it like a rheostat.

Comment: I think theres a typo "(linear with wind speed) " will be wind direction

Comment: @user1999 fixed and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why they choose one or other method is uncertain - but the current source driven method should work well enough.

Change 741 opamp to LM324 (quad) or LM358 (dual)

The transistor provides a current source of about 0.5 mA- see below.
The windvane is connected as a variable resistor (2 wire connection) and not as a potentiometer (3 wire connection). Both arrangements return the same result given suitable circuitry. The 3 wire voltage divider is somewhat more flexible - at the cost mainly of the extra wire.

The 0.5 mA drops a voltage in the windvane resistance. Say R = 0 to 10,000 ohms then V = IR = 0.0005 x 0 to 10000 = 0 to 5 volts.
The two opamps act as unity gain buffers and R3:R4 divide the voltage to a desired Vout range.
**______________**

**Current source:**

The voltage across R1 is Vzener + Vdiode - Vbe_transistor != Vzener.
So current in R1 = I = V/R = 5.6/11.7k ~= 0.5 mA.

When dropped across the 0-10k vane resistor this gives Vout of 0 - 5V.

---

**Wind vane**

The text is self contradictory. They say the vane resistor is potentiometric but make it clear that they use it as 0 - 10k variable resistor

[From here](https://metnet.imd.gov.in/mausamdocs/15948_F.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I didn't get how the O/P terminals above is connected to the wind wave. Doesn't such a potentiometric wind vane have 3 terminals? Which
>      terminals are connected to the O/P in this case?

The wind vane is configured internally as a variable resistor, rather than a ratiometric divider, hence why there are only two terminals. We can't be certain why it has been designed like this, but it might be to reduce the number of wires required to connect it, or perhaps due to some other design constraint.

> 2. Why use a current source? Wouldn't a voltage source and a ratiometric measurement work instead?

By using a current source, the voltage that develops across the sensor output is linearly proportional to the wind direction (V = I * Rsensor, where I is constant). If you use a voltage divider instead the output is V = 12 * Rsensor / (Rsensor + Rdivider). This is not a linear relationship, so some sort of linearisation circuit would be required after the preamplifier.

These days that isn't a big deal, but before cheap mixed signal microcontrollers became ubiquitous it was a complication that was useful to avoid.

Comment: "so some sort of linearisation circuit would be required after the preamplifier." What can that be? You mean an algorithm converts the non linear relationship to a linear one? I never saw such thing.